# Is a linear functional of a convex function of $f$ a convex functional of $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^2$. Let $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a convex function. My question is, is the following a convex functional of $f$?

$$\int\limits^1_{0}v_1(x)g(f_1(x))dx+\int\limits^1_{0}v_2(x)g(f_2(x))dx$$

Clearly, if $g$ is the identity map then the above is a linear functional of $f$. But I'm struggling to understand whether it is convex, more generally.

Comment: So naming $F(f) = F((f_1,f_2))$ the functional would help. Now consider two functions $f = (f_1,f_2)$ and $h = (h_1,h_2)$. What is the necessary condition for $F$ to be convex?

Comment: I see your point. So guess we can't say that (that $F$ is convex) unless $v_1, v_2 \geq 0$?

Comment: For $F$ to be convex you would want $F$ to satisfy $F(tf +(1-t)h) \leq tF(f) + (1-t)F(h)$ for every $ t \in [0,1]$. So yes, at the point when you'll try to get the inequality, $g$ will behave good as it is already convex, but you do not know if the  product $υ_i g$ and as a result the whole integral, will satisfy the corresponding inequality. As you said, if we knew $υ_1 , υ_2 \geq 0$ then there would be no problem.